# how can i solve this error from node.js. "NJS-016: buffer is too small for OUT binds"

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I'm Trying to connect node.js to oracledb. and Im Trying to SELECT to DB VIEW. I coding this.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT } = require('oracledb');

router.use(bodyParser.json());

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {

  let connection;

  let binds = [];
  Buffer.from(binds);

  let options = { prefetchRows: 100001, fetchArraySize: 100000, resultSet: false, outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT, maxRows: 100000};

  try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
          user: (user),
          password: (password),
          connectString: (connectString),
      });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
  }

    const mybatisMapper = require('mybatis-mapper');
    let param = req.body;

    mybatisMapper.createMapper(['./routes/models/'+param.mapper+'.xml']);
    let time = new Date();
    console.log('## '+time+' ##');
    console.log('\n Called Mapper Name = ' + param.mapper);

    let format = { language: 'sql', indent: ' '};

    let query = mybatisMapper.getStatement(param.mapper, param.mapper_id, param, format);
    console.log("\n============== Node Mybatis Query Log Start =========\n");
    console.log('* mapper namespace : ' + param.mapper + '.' + param.mapper_id || '*\n');
    console.log(query || '\n');

    try {

      let result = await connection.execute(query, binds, options);

      let time2 = new Date();
      console.log('## '+time2+' ##');
      console.log('## RESULT DATA LIST ## \n', result);
      let json = JSON.stringify(result);
      res.send({json});
      console.log('======== Node Mybatis Query Log End =========\n');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('db error : ' + err);
        res.send({ error : err.message });
    } finally {
      if (connection) {
          try {
              await connection.close();
          } catch (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
          }
      }
    }

});
  
  module.exports = router;
```

i trying to increase fetchArraySize and prefetchRows, maxRows. but it's not working.

DB Table has 10 Columns, and 500 rows. and query is "SELECT * FROM (VIEW NAME)"

weird things is if I SELECT just 3 Columns than it's Working.

just only problem is I SELECT all Data from VIEW.

Help me pls... T_T

I Tried Increased fetchArraySize, maxRows.

Comment: What version driver and Instant Client?  The error maybe a buglet (ie. not the best error message) for an out-of-memory-condition because you have have extremely (and probably not beneficial) prefetch & array sizes.  Don't set prefetchRows.  Set fetchArraySize somewhere like 1000 or 10000.  It's a long time since I've seen anyone set maxRows - do you need to set it?

Comment: instant Client is oracle 11g 64-bit. My company contracted so low version oracledb. is this problem? prefetchRows set is that I saw in oracle official doc. maxRows either.

Comment: What's the version of node-oracledb itself?  The problem with setting both prefetchRows and fetchArraySize is that this doubles the memory, and your error is possibly memory related.  So do a test that doesn't set prefetchRows. And set fetchArraySize to a smaller, more reasonable value.  I plan to change the guidance in the doc about this and just show setting fetchArraySize for the big query scenario.

Comment: @ChristopherJones i tried to delete prefetchRows and maxRows, and change a fetchArraySize to reasonable size ( i tested 100 - 5000 ) but Same Error message is Came still. should i Modify Query? now Query is just 'SELECT * FROM [TABLE]'.

Comment: You should update you question with a reproducible testcase including data.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I solve this Problem. it was oracle Clients version issue. thanks for you help :)